# Trying to apply numerical method with Do

Tags: numerics, procedural-programming, numerical-value, number-representation, infinite-loop

I am trying the following scheme to learn to implement an iteration using Do loop. I tried to implement the same method using for loop but with same errors. I, therefore, turned to the Do loop to implement the method.

```
Fa1n[i_, j_] := (
  Fa1n[i, 0] = i;
  Fa1n[i, -1] = 0;
  Do[Fa1n[i, k + 1] = Fa1n[i, k] + Fa1n[i + 1, k];
   Fa1n[i + 1, k + 1] = Fa1n[i + 1, k] + Fa1n[i + 2, k], {k, 0, 
    j + 1}];
  Print[Fa1n[i, j]])
Table[{k1, Abs[Fa1n[0, k1]]}, {k1, 0, 32}] // Quiet
```

I am getting the following error which I also got in case of for loop.

```
Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,2]]]

Null

Null

Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,4]]]

Null

Null

Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,6]]]

Null

Null

Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,8]]]

Null

Null

Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,10]]]

Null

Null

Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,12]]]

Null

Null

Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,14]]]

Null

Null

Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,16]]]

Null

Null

Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,18]]]

Null

Null

Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,20]]]

Null

Null

Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,22]]]

Null

Null

41335+90 Null+17 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,2]]]+15 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,4]]]+13 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,6]]]+11 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,8]]]+9 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,10]]]+7 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,12]]]+5 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,14]]]+3 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,16]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,18]]]+19 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,0]]]+17 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,2]]]+15 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,4]]]+13 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,6]]]+11 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,8]]]+9 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,10]]]+7 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,12]]]+5 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,14]]]+3 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,16]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,18]]]

2487121+2160 Null+680 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,2]]]+455 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,4]]]+286 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,6]]]+165 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,8]]]+84 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,10]]]+35 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,12]]]+10 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,14]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,16]]]+969 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,0]]]+680 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,2]]]+455 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,4]]]+286 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,6]]]+165 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,8]]]+84 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,10]]]+35 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,12]]]+10 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,14]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,16]]]

37271724+16044 Null+6188 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,2]]]+3003 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,4]]]+1287 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,6]]]+462 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,8]]]+126 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,10]]]+21 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,12]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,14]]]+11628 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,0]]]+6188 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,2]]]+3003 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,4]]]+1287 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,6]]]+462 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,8]]]+126 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,10]]]+21 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,12]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,14]]]

220946084+47616 Null+19448 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,2]]]+6435 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,4]]]+1716 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,6]]]+330 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,8]]]+36 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,10]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,12]]]+50388 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,0]]]+19448 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,2]]]+6435 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,4]]]+1716 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,6]]]+330 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,8]]]+36 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,10]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,12]]]

646886594+62292 Null+24310 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,2]]]+5005 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,4]]]+715 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,6]]]+55 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,8]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,10]]]+92378 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,0]]]+24310 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,2]]]+5005 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,4]]]+715 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,6]]]+55 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,8]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,10]]]

1111331934+36568 Null+12376 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,2]]]+1365 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,4]]]+78 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,6]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,8]]]+75582 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,0]]]+12376 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,2]]]+1365 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,4]]]+78 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,6]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,8]]]

1350821340+9142 Null+2380 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,2]]]+105 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,4]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,6]]]+27132 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,0]]]+2380 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,2]]]+105 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,4]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,6]]]

1404551508+832 Null+136 Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,2]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,4]]]+3876 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,0]]]+136 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,2]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,4]]]

1405969983+18 Null+Hold[Print[Fa1n[678,2]]]+171 Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,0]]]+Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,2]]]

1401803243+210 Null+Hold[Print[Fa1n[679,0]]]

1397751131+Hold[Print[Fa1n[677,0]]]

1393557504

1389349087+21 Null

1385168225+Null

1380974592

1376780288

1372585984

1368377777+21 Null

1364196715+Null

1360003072

1355808768

1351614464

1347420160

1343225856

1339031552

1334837248

1330642944

1326435157+21 Null

1322253695+Null

1318060032

1313865728

1309671424

1305477120

1301282816

1297088512

1292894208

1288699904

1284505600

1280311296

1276116992

1271922688

1267728384

1263534080

1259339776

1255145472

1250951168

1246756864

1242549917+21 Null

1238367655+Null

1234173952

1229979648

1225785344

1221591040

1217396736

1213202432

1209008128

1204813824

1200619520

1196425216

1192230912

1188036608

1183842304

1179648000

1175453696

1171259392

1167065088

1162870784

1158676480

1154482176

1150287872

1146093568

1141899264

1137704960

1133510656

1129316352

1125122048

1120927744

1116733440

1112539136

1108344832

2071724032+Null

3855613952+4 Null

3978035200+5 Null

4254302208+7 Null

4323557376+9 Null

4331468800+11 Null

4321655808+13 Null

4306816896+15 Null

4290573376+17 Null

4273941816+19 Null

4257095510+231 Null

4240440311+Null

4223664128

4206886912

4190109696

4173332480

4156555264

4139778048

4123000832

4106223616

4089446400

4072669184

4055891968

4039114752

4022337536

4005560320

3988783104

3972005888

3955228672

3938451456

3921674240

3904897024

3888119808

3871342592

3854565376

3837788160

3821010944

3804233728

3787456512

3770679296

3753902080

3737124864

3720347648

3703570432

3686793216

3670016000

3653238784

3636461568

3619684352

3602907136

3586129920

3569352704

3552575488

3535798272

3519021056

3502243840

3485466624

3468689408

3451912192

3435134976

3418357760

3401580544

3384803328

3368026112

3351248896

3334471680

3317694464

3300917248

3284140032

3267362816

3250585600

3233808384

3217031168

3200253952

3183476736

3166699520

3149922304

3133145088

3116367872

3099590656

3082813440

3066036224

3049259008

3032481792

3015704576

2998927360

2982150144

2965372928

2948595712

2931818496

2915041280

2898264064

2881486848

2864709632

2847932416

2831155200

2814370025+23 Null

2797600423+Null

2780823552

2764046336

2747269120

2730491904

2713714688

2696937472

2680160256

2663383040

2646605824

2629828608

2613051392

2596274176

2579496960

2562719744

2545942528

2529165312

2512388096

2495610880

2478833664

2462056448

2445279232

2428502016

2411724800

2394947584

2378170368

2361393152

2344615936

2327838720

2311061504

2294284288

2277507072

2260729856

2243952640

2227175424

2210398208

2193620992

2176843776

2160066560

2143289344

2126512128

2109734912

2092957696

2076180480

2059403264

2042626048

2025848832

2009071616

1992294400

1975517184

1958739968

1941962752

1925185536

1908408320

1891631104

1874853888

1858076672

1841299456

1824522240

1807745024

1790967808

1774190592

1757413376

1740636160

1723858944

1707081728

1690304512

1673527296

1656750080

1639972864

1623195648

1606418432

1589641216

1572864000

1556086784

1539309568

1522532352

1505755136

1488977920

1472200704

1455423488

1438646272

1421869056

1405091840

1388314624

1371537408

1354760192

1337982976

1321205760

1304428544

1287651328

1270874112

1254096896

1237319680

1220542464

1203765248

1186988032

1170210816

1153433600

1136656384

1119879168

1103101952

1086324736

1069547520

1052770304

1035993088

1019215872

1002438656

985661440

968884224

952107008

935329792

918552576

901775360

884998144

868220928

851443712

834666496

817889280

801112064

784334848

767557632

750780416

734003200

717225984

700448768

683671552

666894336

650117120

633339904

616562688

599785472

583008256

566231040

549453824

532676608

515899392

499122176

482344960

465567744

448790528

432013312

415236096

398458880

381681664

364904448

348127232

331350016

314572800

297795584

281018368

264241152

247463936

438304768+Null

771751936+4 Null

1426063360+5 Null

2679111680+5 Null

5012193280+5 Null

9332326400+5 Null

17280532480+5 Null

31792824320+5 Null

58049167360+5 Null
```

it also gave an output given below. I do not understand why there are null in the output. Also if k1 varies from 0 to 4 or to 20 then you wouldn't get any error. But as the number increased I obtained errors.

```
{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 12}, {4, 32}, {5, 80}, {6, 192}, {7, 
  448}, {8, 1024}, {9, 2304}, {10, 5120}, {11, 11264}, {12, 
  24576}, {13, 53248}, {14, 114688}, {15, 245760}, {16, 524288}, {17, 
  1114112}, {18, 2359296}, {19, 4980736}, {20, 10485760}, {21, 
  22020096}, {22, 46137344}, {23, 96468992}, {24, 201326592}, {25, 
  419430400}, {26, 872415232}, {27, 1811939328}, {28, 
  3758096384}, {29, 7784628224}, {30, Abs[11811160064 + Null]}, {31, 
  Abs[22347251712 + 3 Null]}, {32, Abs[Null]}}
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution without `Do` loop. I will use the symbol `g`, so if you have old definitions for `g`, please delete them using `Clear[g]` or restart Mathematica:

```
g[i_,0]  := i;
g[i_,-1] := 0;
g[i_,k_] := g[i,k] = g[i,k-1] + g[i+1,k-1];
```

Plot:

```
Table[{k,Abs[g[0,k]]},{k,0,32}] // ListLogPlot
```

[image]

**Note.** The third line could have been

```
g[i_,k_] := g[i,k-1] + g[i+1,k-1];
```

but this will be much slower. See the tutorial [Functions That Remember Values They Have Found](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#202640595) also known as memoization.

Comment: In your code when it goes to calculate g[0,2] it needs the value of g[1,1] which is not previously calculated. Then how does it run?

Comment: Even if g[1,1] was not calculated yet, it does fit the pattern g[i_,k_] so Mathematica evaluates that. Only after it is done with that, does it continue with the g[0,2] evaluation. This is recursion, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/717839) for example.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm has a bug.

Look at your function Fa1n and consider: ClearFa1n]; Fa1n[0,0]::

First, it sets Fa1n[0,0]=0, Fa1n[0,-1]=0 and then Fa1n[0,1]= Fa1n[0,0]+Fa1n[1,0]. However Fa1n[1,0] is not yet defined, what leads to an infinite recursion.

Comment: In my code Fa1[I,0]=I. That means Fa1[1,0]].@Daniel Huber